# Does ROS Python library shadow or break other python systems?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS puts `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` in `PYTHONPATH`.  This is then prepended to the system path when python2 or python3 is used.  Is this likely to shadow or break other python packages from Anaconda3 (in python3 or python2 virtual environments) ?  I looked in the ROS directory and it all seems very ROS specific, but since I am completely new to python I am not sure.

I have solved my problems with Anaconda3 changing the default version of python to 3.6, so now just concerned with the presence of python2 libraries in the python systempath.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287296/does-ros-python-library-shadow-or-break-other-python-systems-?/) by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2018-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are three ways you can approach this.

1. You can use virtualenv and install anaconda3 inside it, so that there are no conflicts between the different versions of Python.
2. You can use two different bash files, in which one sources the python of anaconda3, and the other sources the python used for ROS.
3. You can create symlinks in the Path folder to link anaconda3 python to `python3` and ROS python2 to `python` and also, the Python2 pip to `pip` and Python3 pip to `pip3`

I personally prefer the 1st method, as it is the cleanest and easiest. The second is easy to work around. The third one will likely break your system, as it makes the system extremely complex.
Can you share what packages you want to install in Anaconda3?

---

Originally posted by [Akash Purandare](https://answers.ros.org/users/34280/akash-purandare/) with karma: 61 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elpidiovaldez](https://answers.ros.org/users/28066/elpidiovaldez/) on 2018-05-03**:
I use a lot of 'datascience'  and AI packages like Tensorflow, numpy, scipy, scilearn, pandas, pillow, opencv.

**Comment by [Akash Purandare](https://answers.ros.org/users/34280/akash-purandare/) on 2018-05-04**:
As far as I know, if you know how to type Data Science codes in Python 3, you can do so in Python 2 as well. As far as these packages are concerned, the ROS scripts do run on the local environment of python, hence, you will be able to merge all of these to achieve the results. Install them using pip